# PHPUnit and ionCube conflict

Tags: php, phpunit, ioncube

I get this error when I try to run test cases that need ionCube:
The file **path/to/file.php** has been encoded with the [ionCube PHP Encoder](http://www.ioncube.com) and requires the free ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so [ionCube PHP Loader](http://www.ioncube.com/loader_download/) to be installed.
Fatal error occurred in test case Class_Name->testCaseName.
TearDown for fatal-error-failed-test and tearDownAfterClass were successfully called after fatal error occurred.

I have PHPUnit 4.5.0.

ionCube is installed correctly as I can see it with phpinfo() and the website is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit may be using a different `php.ini` file than your website, so you'll see the ionCube Loader on a webpage generated by `<?php phpinfo();`.

To confirm, type in `php -i` to see the CLI version of `phpinfo()` (or `php -i | grep -i ioncube` to see if the ionCube Loader is installed, and `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"` to see where your CLI PHP configuration file lives).

Do note that PHPUnit may be using a completely different `php.ini` file still - you'll have to look into your own setup for more details.

Once you've located the configuration file, you should be able to copy and paste the `zend_extension` line from your working `php.ini` file, provided you have the same PHP setups for both CLI and CGI.

If you're stuck and/or it's still not working, you can also create a ticket at [ionCube's Helpdesk](http://support.ioncube.com).

Comment: Thanks, I've put the zend_extension line in the CLI PHP configuration file and it seems to work. Thanks a lot.